# Action by left coset multiplication

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-homomorphism

So I have this example in my thesis that you can define an action of a group $G$ on G/H (where $H \lhd G$) like this: $\phi_g(aH)=gaH$. I thought it was simple enough that I didn't need to prove it's true, except now I tried and I can't prove it!

We say that $G$ acts on $G/H$ if there's a homomorphism $\phi: G:\to Aut G/H$, right? Well, so I need to prove two things: $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $Aut G/H$, and $\phi_g$ is an automorphism of $G/H$. I can prove the first claim, but not the second.

If $\phi_g$ is an automorphism of $G/H$, then 
$$\phi_g(aHbH)=\phi_g(aH)\phi_g(bH),$$

but $\phi_g(aHbH)=\phi_g(abH)=gabH$, while $\phi_g(aH)\phi_g(bH)=gaHgbH=gagbH$, and I don't see why $gabH$ should be the same as $gagbH$. I'm clearly missing something really simple, but I really don't know what!

Comment: $\phi$ does not have to be a morphism to $Aut(G/H)$ but to $Sym(G/H)$, since you have an action of $G$ on the *set* $G/H$. Moreover what should $Aut(G/H)$ be? In the same vein, you write $aHbH = abH$ but this is only true for a *normal* subgroup $H$.

Comment: In summary: you assumed an *algebraic structure* on $G/H$, which is not the case for an arbitrary $H \leq G$.

Comment: Maybe a bit easier to work with is this (equivalent) definition: A (left) action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is given by a map $G\times X\rightarrow X$, $(g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x$ satisfying: (1) $1\cdot x = x$ for all $x\in X$ and (2) $g\cdot (h\cdot x) = (gh)\cdot x$ for all $g,h\in G$, $x\in X$.

Comment: @M.U., my bad $H$ was supposed to be normal, but it still doesn't work for the same reason—or at least, I can't get it to work.

Comment: @user218931, I think that definition only covers the part about $\phi$ being a homomorphism between $G$ and $Aut G/H$, but I also need to show that $\phi_g$ is an automorphism of $G/H$.

Comment: @Nicola. No you don't. You have a group $G$ acting on a **set** $X$ (in your case $G/H$ but it doesn't matter). Having a group action (e.g. like user218931 wrote) is the same thing as having a morphism from $G$ to $Sym(X)$, i.e. the set of bijections $X \to X$. Do you see the **important** difference? It seems to me as you may again work through the definition of a *group action* as you may have not unterstood correctly.

Comment: I really don't understand! I'm following the textbook definition given in Suzuki's Group theory I, and it is made very clear that, given two groups $G$ and $H$, an action of $G$ on $H$ is defined as a homomorphism from $G$ into $Aut H$, and that $\phi(g)$ (i.e. $\phi_g$) is an automorphism of $H$. In my case, $G$ acts on $G/H$, so according to this definition, $\phi$ should be an automorphism og $G/H$. I'm not sure if you're saying that Suzuki's definition is the same as your comment above, or that it doesn't apply.

Comment: $G$ is acting on $G/H$ viewed as a *set*, not as a group (even if $H$ is normal in $G$, so that $G/H$ is a group)! In this case, the definition of Suzuki doesn't apply. Please refer to the comments of @M.U.

Comment: @user218931 Which means I was using the wrong example, since I need an action of a group on another group. All conditions check out except automorphism, so I picked the wrong example. Thanks to both of you for helping me see that! :)

Comment: If you really want to make $G$ act on $G/H$ as a group ($H$ normal in $G$), then you might check $(g,aH)\mapsto gag^{-1}H$.